# testing email gets sent in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, cucumber, actionmailer

I have a list of stories assigned to me in Cucumber, one of them being "Then the user should receive a confirmation email". I think testing that the user receives it is beyond the power of the application, but how can I test that an email had just been sent?

Answer (score 7):

You can use this step definition :

```
Then "the user should receive a confirmation email" do
  # this will get the first email, so we can check the email headers and body.
  email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first
  email.from.should == "admin@example.com"
  email.to.should == @user.email
  email.body.should include("some key word or something....")
end
```

Tested with Rails 3.2

[Source](http://davidangga.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/testing-action-mailer-with-cucumber/)

Answer (score 2):

[email_spec](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec) + [action_mailer_cache_delivery](https://github.com/p0deje/action_mailer_cache_delivery) gems are your friends for doing this

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to verify the `last_response` after some action ocurrs, like, a user click  on a button, or something like that.

Or if you are updating a record after doing something, check for the `updated_at` attribute to see if it was changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check [dockyard/capybara-email](https://github.com/dockyard/capybara-email) gem:

```
feature 'Emailer' do
  background do
    # will clear the message queue
    clear_emails
    visit email_trigger_path
    # Will find an email sent to test@example.com
    # and set `current_email`
    open_email('test@example.com')
  end

  scenario 'following a link' do
    current_email.click_link 'your profile'
    expect(page).to have_content 'Profile page'
  end

  scenario 'testing for content' do
    expect(current_email).to have_content 'Hello Joe!'
  end

  scenario 'testing for a custom header' do
    expect(current_email.headers).to include 'header-key'
  end

  scenario 'testing for a custom header value' do
    expect(current_email.header('header-key')).to eq 'header_value'
  end

  scenario 'view the email body in your browser' do
    # the `launchy` gem is required
    current_email.save_and_open
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [PutsBox](http://putsbox.com). You can send an email to whatever-you-want@putsbox.com, wait for a few seconds (SMTP stuff ins't instantaneous) then check your email via http://preview.putsbox.com/p/whatever-you-want/last.

This [post tutorial](http://www.pablocantero.com/blog/2015/08/05/test-emails-with-automated-testing-tools/) has some examples.